# autocomplete in gridview textbox

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have two `gridview` `textbox` columns. I'm using auto-complete in the `gridview`'s `textbox` column individually, but both `gridview` `textbox` columns'
auto-complete are mixing data across these columns.

How can I display auto-complete without mixing data from `article_code` and `yarn_count`?

Here is my code:

```
    AutoCompleteStringCollection namesCollection4=new AutoCompleteStringCollection(); 
string query = "select article_code from article_production";
con.Open();
SqlCommand cmb = new SqlCommand(query, con);
SqlDataReader dr = cmb.ExecuteReader();
if (dr.HasRows == true)
{
    while (dr.Read())
    {
        namesCollection4.Add(dr["article_code"].ToString());

    }
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Data not found");
}

con.Close();
dr.Close();
int column = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;

if(column==8)
{
    TextBox tb = e.Control as TextBox;

    if (tb != null)
    {
        tb.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
        tb.AutoCompleteCustomSource = namesCollection4;
        tb.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;

    }

}
```

Second Gridview Columns

```
 AutoCompleteStringCollection namesCollection1=new AutoCompleteStringCollection(); 
string query1 = "select yarn_count from yarn";
con.Open();
SqlCommand cmb1 = new SqlCommand(query1, con);
SqlDataReader dr1 = cmb1.ExecuteReader();
if (dr1.HasRows == true)
{
    while (dr1.Read())
    {
        namesCollection1.Add(dr1["yarn_count"].ToString());

    }
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Data not found");
}

con.Close();
dr1.Close();
int column1 = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;

if (column1 == 9)
{

    TextBox tb1 = e.Control as TextBox;

    if (tb1 != null)
    {
        tb1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
        tb1.AutoCompleteCustomSource = namesCollection1;
        tb1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
    }

}
```

Comment: On what event are you calling this code?

Comment: Are you using windows forms? WPF? Silverlight? Or something else for this?

Comment: @Ryan Gates m work on winform application

Comment: gridvieweditcontrolshowing

Comment: @user2491383 look in this `e.Control as TextBox;` what is `e`? I don't see any definition of it in your code?

Comment: its working code dude problem is that my data mixing in both columns

Comment: otherwise e is find the control in gridview if e is textbox

Comment: @user2491383 I don't understand, what is type of `e`? You might pick it up in some context but didn't post the whole code.

Comment: I was unable to reproduce your issue using a list of strings for the Autocompletion source. It looks like it is either a data issue or as @KingKing was asking something to do with using `e` as a Textbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 AutoCompleteStringCollection namesCollection1=new AutoCompleteStringCollection(); 
string query1 = "select yarn_count from yarn";
con.Open();
SqlCommand cmb1 = new SqlCommand(query1, con);
SqlDataReader dr1 = cmb1.ExecuteReader();
if (dr1.HasRows == true)
{
    while (dr1.Read())
    {
        namesCollection1.Add(dr1["yarn_count"].ToString());

    }
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Data not found");
}

con.Close();
dr1.Close();
int column1 = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;

if (column1 == 9)
{

    TextBox tb1 = e.Control as TextBox;

    if (tb1 != null)
    {
        tb1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
        tb1.AutoCompleteCustomSource = namesCollection1;
        tb1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
    }

}
else
{
namesCollection1.Clear();
}
finally{con.Close();}
```

> > I Find the Solution i forgot to write else conditioned

Answer (score 0):

I've tested and this should work as you want:

```
//EditingControlShowing event handler for your DataGridView
private void dataGridView_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
        DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl cellEdit = e.Control as DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl;
        cellEdit.AutoCompleteCustomSource = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
        cellEdit.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
        cellEdit.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
        int colIndex = dataGridView.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;
        if (colIndex == 8) cellEdit.AutoCompleteCustomSource.AddRange(new string[] { "Aaaa", "Bbbb", "Cccc" });
        else if (colIndex == 9) cellEdit.AutoCompleteCustomSource.AddRange(new string[] { "1234", "5678" });            
}
```

I'm not sure of what type your `namesCollection` is, if you want to assign to `AutoCompleteSource` property, you have to be sure it's type of `AutoCompleteStringCollection`.

Comment: AutoCompleteStringCollection namesCollection=new AutoCompleteStringCollection()

Comment: @user2491383 but my code is working in custom range, why is that?

Comment: m updating my code now see and wat u post its work perfect but its not  from Database

Comment: @user2491383 could you show an example of `mixing data from article_code and yarn_count`? What does it look like? As I understand your problem is the auto-complete list is the same for all the cells, right? So what are the details of that list?

Comment: yarn and article both show on every gridview column through my code